# custom syntax highlighting not working via ~/.vimrc

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I am trying to use dracula (https://draculatheme.com/vim/) for syntax highlighting in vim 8. I have `dracula.vim` in my `~/.vim/colors` directory, and if I set `:colorscheme dracula` inside vim, then it works.

However, if I try to replicate this via vimrc, I get errors.

Specifically, if I make my `~/.vimrc` file either:

```
syntax enable
colorscheme dracula
```

or just:

```
colorscheme dracula
```

I get the following errors when I run vim:

```
E116: Invalid arguments for function <SNR>2_h
line  186:
E121: Undefined variable: s:green
E116: Invalid arguments for function <SNR>2_h
line  187:
E121: Undefined variable: s:comment
E116: Invalid arguments for function <SNR>2_h
line  188:
E121: Undefined variable: s:cyan
E116: Invalid arguments for function <SNR>2_h
line  190:
E121: Undefined variable: s:orange
E116: Invalid arguments for function <SNR>2_h
line  191:
E121: Undefined variable: s:bg
E116: Invalid arguments for function <SNR>2_h
line  192:
E121: Undefined variable: s:red
E116: Invalid arguments for function <SNR>2_h
line  202:
E121: Undefined variable: s:fg
E116: Invalid arguments for function <SNR>2_h
line  203:
E121: Undefined variable: s:bglighter
```

etc.

After the errors, vim opens but with no syntax highlighting.

I've also tried to use vundle. I've cloned vundle per the instructions on the git, and made my ~/.vimrc as follows:

```
set nocompatible
filetype off

set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()

Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'

Plugin 'dracula/vim'

call vundle#end()
filetype plugin indent on
```

I've then run `:PluginInstall` with success. But no syntax highlighting. If I add the line `syntax on` to my vimrc, then I do get syntax highlighting, but it's the default colours rather than the dracula theme.

For reference,

```
$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Jul 26 2019 05:29:00)
Included patches: 1-1749
Compiled by [me]
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               -farsi             -mouse_sysmouse    -tag_any_white
+arabic            +file_in_path      +mouse_urxvt       -tcl
+autocmd           +find_in_path      +mouse_xterm       +termguicolors
+autochdir         +float             +multi_byte        +terminal
-autoservername    +folding           +multi_lang        +terminfo
-balloon_eval      -footer            -mzscheme          +termresponse
+balloon_eval_term +fork()            +netbeans_intg     +textobjects
-browse            +gettext           +num64             +textprop
++builtin_terms    -hangul_input      +packages          +timers
+byte_offset       +iconv             +path_extra        +title
+channel           +insert_expand     -perl              -toolbar
+cindent           +job               +persistent_undo   +user_commands
-clientserver      +jumplist          +postscript        +vartabs
-clipboard         +keymap            +printer           +vertsplit
+cmdline_compl     +lambda            +profile           +virtualedit
+cmdline_hist      +langmap           +python            +visual
+cmdline_info      +libcall           -python3           +visualextra
+comments          +linebreak         +quickfix          +viminfo
+conceal           +lispindent        +reltime           +vreplace
+cryptv            +listcmds          +rightleft         +wildignore
+cscope            +localmap          -ruby              +wildmenu
+cursorbind        -lua               +scrollbind        +windows
+cursorshape       +menu              +signs             +writebackup
+dialog_con        +mksession         +smartindent       -X11
+diff              +modify_fname      -sound             -xfontset
+digraphs          +mouse             +spell             -xim
-dnd               -mouseshape        +startuptime       -xpm
-ebcdic            +mouse_dec         +statusline        -xsmp
+emacs_tags        -mouse_gpm         -sun_workshop      -xterm_clipboard
+eval              -mouse_jsbterm     +syntax            -xterm_save
+ex_extra          +mouse_netterm     +tag_binary        
+extra_search      +mouse_sgr         -tag_old_static    
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/local/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -std=gnu99 -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H     -g -O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1       
Linking: gcc -std=gnu99   -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -o vim        -lm -ltinfo -lnsl  -lselinux  -ldl    -L/usr/lib64/python2.7/config -lpython2.7 -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -Xlinker -export-dynamic
```

Comment: Hi paul, I’m one of the dracula maintainers. Can you open an issue on GitHub and tell us what version of dracula you are using?

Comment: `filetype off` did you try removing that and see if it works? I know you're setting in back on, but are you doing it before or after you enable syntax and the colorscheme?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Thanks for getting in touch, I just copied this over to the git. @Harish, just tried removing `filetype off`, but no difference.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @funnydman we ended up solving this over on GitHub IIRC